# cakePHP : can't login to go to the edit page of a user

Tags: cakephp, authentication, hash, forms-authentication

When I try to edit a user I get a login form, when I try to login it shows me 'The username and/or password is incorrect' from the UsersController. Even though the username and password is correct.

My User Table :

```
1 user_id bigint(11) AUTO_INCREMENT 
2 user_username varchar(45) utf8_general_ci
3 user_email varchar(255) utf8_general_ci
4 user_password varchar(255) utf8_general_ci
5 user_image varchar(255) utf8_general_ci
6 user_created timestamp CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
7 user_modified timestamp
8 user_deleted timestamp
9 user_lastlogin timestamp
10 user_locked timestamp            
11 user_confirmed timestamp     
12 person_id bigint(20)
```

This is in my User Model:

```
public function beforeSave($options=array()){
    parent::beforeSave();
    if (!empty($this->data['User']['user_password'])){
        $this->data['User']['user_password'] = Security::hash($this->data['User']['user_password'], 'sha256', true);
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is in my AppController :

```
public $components = array(
   'DebugKit.Toolbar',
   'Session', 
   'Auth' => array(
      'authenticate' => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'username' => 'user_username',
                'password' => 'user_password'
            ),
            'passwordHasher' => array(
                'className' => 'Simple',
                'hashType' => 'sha256'
            )
        )
    ),
      'loginRedirect' => array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'index'),
      'logoutRedirect' => array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'index'),
      'AuthError' => 'You cannot access that page',
      'authorize'=>array('Controller')
   )
);

public function isAuthorized($user){
   return true;
}

public function beforeFilter() {
   $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
}
```

This is in My login.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('user_username');
echo $this->Form->input('user_password', array('type'=>'password'));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

This is in my UsersController :

```
public function beforeFilter(){
   parent::beforeFilter();
   $this->Auth->allow('add');
}

public function login(){
   if ($this->request->is('post')){
      if($this->Auth->login()){
         $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
         } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(_('The username and/or password is incorrect'));
         }
      }
}

public function logout(){
   $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

I've been looking for a while on this. Changing the name of user_password to password, changing the Type, changing the varchar(255) to (40),... Nothing seems to resolve this. Maybe it has something to do with the hashing but I think I've did everything right with that as well.

Maybe something else you should know: I'm working with IIS, do I need to do some sort of configuration?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use fields 'username' and 'password' arbitrarily. Also AuthComponent::password is deprecated since 2.4. In your AuthComponent configuration, you may add the following parameters:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'user_username',
                    'password' => 'user_password'
                ),
                'passwordHasher' => array(
                    'className' => 'Simple',
                    'hashType' => 'sha256'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

In your auth model:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    parent::beforeSave();
    if (!empty($this->data['Model']['password'])) {
        $this->data['Model']['password'] = Security::hash($this->data['Model']['password'], 'sha256', true);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You may want to edit your original answer instead of creating new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to change user_username in the database also to username.

So I changed:

```
2 user_username varchar(45) utf8_general_ci
4 user_password varchar(255) utf8_general_ci
```

To:

```
2 username varchar(45) utf8_general_ci
4 password varchar(255) utf8_general_ci
```

And also changed those 2 in my cakePHP project.

However I'm wondering if you can change the password and username, that are the default values for using Auth in cakePHP?